# From localhost:3000/admin to localhost:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building a node.js app. I would like that after the admin has successfully uploaded data the homepage is rendered, that is, from `localhost:3000/admin` to `localhost:3000`. I've tried with the code below:

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=>{upload(req, res, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.render('admin', {msg: err});
  }else{
    return res.redirect('index');
  }
}
```

and this is the index.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

but despite the ***title*** being defined index.js and express routing being fine am getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: E:\Documents\Computer and Coding\PlayGround\PROJECTS\Catalogue\views\index.ejs:4
    2| <html>
    3|   <head>
 >> 4|     <title><%= title %></title>
    5|     <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    6|   </head>
    7|   <body>

title is not defined
```

Comment: _"but despite the title being defined "_ Defined where?

Comment: In the index.js file in the routes folder

Comment: does that redirect actually work? You questions title makes it sound like the redirect DOESN'T work

Comment: I have tried changing from the redirect to render but the same error results, that is the main problem the page I want to be rendered is not being rendered

Answer (score 4):

If you want send variable `title` from your server, change this line:

```
res.render('admin', {msg: err});
```

to:

```
res.render('admin', {msg: err, title: <your title here>});
```

Comment: for sure it will work but why should I do so when it is already defined in the index.js file then it is the index page that I want to render not the admin page.

Comment: Ejs is a templating language, it will render from .ejs file.
And it was render from server, not from client.

Comment: You just can send variable for it with option of `res.render` or other .ejs file(your file include).

Comment: Okay, what about the redirecting back to the homepage ?

Comment: Sorry, but you should up load code of your homepage.
Your home has this code too :

    <title><%= title %></title>